# Tab-bar controller for master detail app

Tags: iphone, ios7, master-detail

I have a master detail app embedded in a tab bar controller. Its working fine. When i enter the detail app and move to another tab and return to this tab, it will still be detail control, where i need it go back to the master app every time i click the tab button. Can anyone say how to do this??

I have heard of

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)
```

But what should go into this to make it always open the master part of the navigation.

Comment: unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Use the delegate method like this

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
  if (viewController != tabBarItemForNavControllerTab) {
    [self.navControllerInFirstTab popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
  }
}
```

For your case,

```
if (tabBarController.selectedIndex == 0) 
   {
     // First Tab is selected, load the ViewController you want
   }
```

Comment: Hi, i dont have any navControllers and all are UIviewcontrollers, cant we replicate the above with UIviewcontrollerS?

Comment: Then edit the if condition. Now check the edited answer

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, placed this inside the if condition

ProjectControllerViewController *p = [[ProjectControllerViewController alloc]init];
        [self presentViewController:p animated:NO completion:nil];

But what i want is this view inside the tabbarcontroller, now its opening as a new tap

Comment: How are you moving to detailsViewController from masterViewController?

Comment: I have a master detail app embedded inside tabbar controller, i am moving to detail app, but click of table items in master

Comment: So, you are using Storyboard.. rite?

Comment: Yes, i am calling the if inside the tabbar view controller. Inside the tabbar view controller, there is a masterview app as one of the tab

Comment: Can you give me your storyboard hierarchy? Just for Tab1.

Comment: Maintabbarcontroller -> 1st master-detail
                     -> 2nd Master-detail
                     -> 3rd view controller
                     -> 4th View controller

here, there is a maintabview controller having 4 tabs. In the first tab is the master detail app, another master detail app in second tab, a view controller in third and a view controller in fourth. Now in the first tab, when i go to details -> go to third tab, come back to first tab and it still remains in details but i need it to be the master one